# How to break down this GRE complex sentence

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction, phrase-usage

> That such a ____ of precedent would be countenanced was itself
>   unprecedented in the court, a bastion of traditionalism.

I am practicing for verbal test in GRE therefore its very important to break down a complex sentence to simple sentences and moreover its better to guess a word for the blank space.

What bothers me is that the above sentence has "would be" and "was" in a complicated way.  Can you please how to  break down the sentence therefore I can easily understand the sentence and guessing  for the blank would be easier.

Comment: Are you sure it's **precedent** and not **precedence**? It may help determine what the *blank* is

Comment: yes  it is **precedent** there. they can be  both used  as adjective. Isn't it?

Answer (score 6):

Subject phrase: {That such a (reversal) of precedent would be countenanced}

predicate:  was

predicate complement: {itself unprecedented in the court {, a bastion of traditionalism}   }

{a bastion of traditionalism} is a noun phrase in apposition to *the court*.

The court was such a bastion of traditionalism that for it to not object to a reversal of precedent was unprecedented.

Why **would be**?

The court is so traditional that its countenancing of a reversal of precedent is contrary to expectation.  The modal **would be** stresses the "remoteness" from fact or expectation.